# Seting Live Data value multiple time only fire the last time to Observer

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

Let say I have a Live Data like this

```
val aLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
```

Then I set its value multiple time like this

```
fun setValueMultipleTimes(){
  aLiveData.value = "1"
  aLiveData.value = "2"
  aLiveData.value = "3"
  aLiveData.value = "4"
}
```

The thing is when I execute setValueMultipleTimes(). only the last value ("4") get fired to aLiveData's Observer

Is there any way I can get "1", "2", "3" fired too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveData is designed to send a single state (that might change over time) to observers. It's not intended for streams of data.  If you have several items of data to send to clients at the same time, then consider making it a `LiveData<Array<String>>` instead of `LiveData<String>`:

```
aLiveData.value = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

If you do actually want to send a stream of data rather than state, consider instead using a Kotlin [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html), which is better for that job.

Comment: Thank you so much (y)